# Change CSS for parent div when child element (input field) is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to change the class of a parent div when a child input text field is selected or the mouse moves over any of the other elements in the container. I've tried using both jQuery and some of the pseudo classes in CSS to no avail.

Javascript:

```
$("input").focus(function () {
     $(this).parent().parent("div").css('background-color','#666');  
});
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="container_to_change">
            <div class="box1">
                &nbsp;
            </div>
            <div class="box2">
                <input type="text" class="data-entry">
            </div>
            <div class="box3">
                &nbsp;
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Also, you could use a `form` element, instead of a `div` to contain the form elements...

Answer (score 2):

As @Ibu suggests, in his comment to the question, you could simply use the `:hover` pseudo-class to effect a change in the `container_to_change` element (depending on what change you wish to apply):

```
.container_to_change:hover {
    background-color: #ffa;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wftBH/)

If, however, you really want to use jQuery for this:

```
$('.container_to_change').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).addClass('newClassName');
    },
    function(){
        $(this).removeClass('newClassName');
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wftBH/1/).

---

**Edited** in response to question, in comments, from wishIdidntsquishthatfish:

> How do you keep the different state though when the user is interacting with the input element inside?

```
$('.container_to_change').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).addClass('newClassName');
    },
    function(){
        if ($(this).find('input').is(':focus')){
            return false; // if the input has focus, prevent the removal of the class-name.
        }
        $(this).removeClass('newClassName');
    }).find('input').focus(
    function(){
        // ensures that the class-name is added in response to keyboard-navigation focus
        $(this).closest('.container_to_change').addClass('newClassName');
    }).blur(
    function(){
        // ensures that the class-name is removed in response to keyboard-navigation focus
        $(this).closest('.container_to_change').removeClass('newClassName');
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wftBH/2/).

References:

- [`:hover` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes).
- [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).
- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).
- [`:focus`](http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/).
- [`focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/).
- [`blur()`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/).

Comment: Thanks for the help. How do you keep the different state though when the user is interacting with the input element inside? I tried most of the CSS pseudo-classes to no avail (active, hover, focus), which is why I started leaning down the jQuery route.

Comment: @wish, please see the edits to the question for an update. And glad to have helped, at least a little..! :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to specify "div" when trying to get the parent of a parent.

```
$('input').focus(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().css('background-color', '#666');
});
```

But why do you care about parents?  You can easily just say:

```
$('input').focus(function(){
    $('.container_to_change').css('background-color','#666');
});
```

And if you're worried about specific input classes, just use:

```
$('.data-entry').focus(function(){
    $('.container_to_change').css('background-color','#666');
});
```

Comment: Sorry that there is no formatting; I spaced it nicely when I wrote it.

Comment: no problem; but you might take a look at the [mark-down help page for formatting guidance](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help/).